# Animate a line drawn in CGContext

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to animate a line or circle drawn using Core Graphics?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to draw a smaller line segment and keep drawing it longer. With a circle you'll need to draw a small arc and keep drawing a larger one until you have a circle.